# Fitnesse error on Hudson slave

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, fitnesse

I have configured fitnesse plugin [version 1.4] with Hudson.
I have set it up to start a new fitnesse server on every job run. Everything work fine when i configure job to run on Hudson Master but when i configure job to run on Hudson slave. I get following error :

```
Connnecting to http://localhost:9998/somepath?test&format=xml&includehtml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:411)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:525)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:208)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:291)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:310)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:987)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:923)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:841)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
    at hudson.plugins.fitnesse.FitnesseExecutor.getHttpBytes(FitnesseExecutor.java:225)
    at hudson.plugins.fitnesse.FitnesseExecutor$1.run(FitnesseExecutor.java:202)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any suggestions to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try connecting connecting it with a different port? It could be that the port is being by some other application and you aren't aware of that. It has happened to me a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error as you described and it turned out that restarting the server hosting FitNesse cleared out the problem, I believe that a connection was never terminated correctly by the FitNesse Service and therefore new connection were refused. Hopefully this helps someone.